# Butterknife bind views to different sources

Tags: android, butterknife

In my activity, I am using two types of views : X type and Y type.

X type views are directly defined in the xml layout file with which I am calling `setContentView()`. For Y type of views, they are present in a dialog which I am inflating in the activity and then adding it as a header view in my listview (which is present in activity xml).

Now, how do I use butterknife to inject both of these view types. If I call `Butterknife.bind(@NonNull Activity target)`, it'd inject only those views which are present in activity xml. And if I call `Butterknife.bind(@NonNull Object target, @NonNull Dialog source)`, it would inject only the views present in that dialog.

Hope I've clearly explained the problem.

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: dont work if you call it once for each view?

Comment: do it doesn't work. It'll see which `bind` statement comes first and then try to find all the annotated views in that parent view and then throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from JW [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1121).

Stating it again for others :

> Create a view holder class for each layout and bind an instance of
>   each individually. There's no way to support binding two layouts into
>   one class.